# How do I find the real user who pushed a commit in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to find out who pushed a particular commit to gitlab - In the commit log (I see the author set via the git client config) , I instead want to see which `gitlab` user's authentication was used to `PUSH` that code ?

PS: There are multiple git specific questions asked and there was no solution provided in the previous questions - want to see if `gitlab` has some specific implementation to solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check who pushed a Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212329/check-who-pushed-a-git-commit)

Comment: I wish there was a way to get "pusher" using GItLab API. It's definitely stored somewhere in the db, but doesn't seem to be available via API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit

Answer (score 6):

2018: I [answered "no" 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20212386/6309), but GitLab offers audit logs of its own: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41231761/6309) **HTTP** and **SSH** requests are logged in different files:

- **HTTP**: `nginx/gitlab_access.log`
- **SSH**: [`gitlab-shell.log`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/logs.html#production-log)

However, that won't give you the SHA1(s) pushed, only the push event date and IP: you still need to cross-reference that with a commit date, to get an idea of who did push a given commit.

---

[GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#new-audit-events) (March 2022) seems to include push events (but for Premium/Ultimate editions only):

> ### New audit events
>
> The GitLab 14.9 release adds support for auditing the following activities:
>
> - Creating a new merge request approval rule.
> - Deleting a merge request approval rule.
> - Approving a merge request. (Supported as streaming audit events only.)
> - Creating, deleting, or revoking a project or group deploy token.
> - Failed attempts to create a project or group deploy token.
> - **Authenticated `git push` or `git pull` commands to a private repository performed over either SSH or HTTPS (Supported as streaming audit events only.)**
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7268).

Answer (score 1):

Only `commit` status can be known. But person who actually `pushed` cannot be known.

Answer (score -2):

because of the confusing nature of your question, I am only able to provide simple answers.
If what you are asking is to see what authentication a particular user has used to PUSH a commit then you should be able to find it based on the remote URL for the repo.
If you are looking to find out who did a specific commit, you can search for it in the Web UI.

Hope this helps, reach out if you have additional questions.