# Monitoring Code Repo if Checked out on Users Computer

Tags: git, testing, tracking, software-design, codebase

Not sure if this is the place to post this question but I was wondering if anyone is aware of any apps which allows you to track your GIT repo code base if it has been checked out on another users computer. When I mean track, I mean prevent them from copying the software from their machine to anywhere else etc... So far from my experience working as a software engineer, I have just been handed a laptop from the company but anyone can easily just take their work and create a duplicate of it.

Companies IP does protect their code / DB but then again, it's very hard to track if your back-end code base has been reproduced for someone else.

I apologize in advance if this has been already answered but I could not find it on StackOverflow or the web thus far.

Comment: It is possible to create an evolution of git that does this. Some call such products: `Defective by design`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I mean track, I mean prevent them from copying the software from their machine to anywhere else etc...

No, that does not exits for Git, or for any other source control system: once you have cloned/checkout a repository, nothing prevents you to copy it elsewhere.
That tracking mechanism would be implemented by a security team, but has nothing to do with Git itself.

What repository hosting servers (like GitHub for Enterprise, or GitLab) can provide is an audit trail of "who" ([IP addresses actually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032769/6309)) *cloned* a repo, but won't know anything of a *copy* once the repo is cloned.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Just want to hear from a few others to see if anyone else might have any ideas too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to track what other people do once your code is cloned, but:

In case your code is compiled and you suspect from someone who could have used your IP without your permission, you can audit the suspected binaries with tools like:

> binwalk
>
> > Focus on unpacking firmwares, but not much else
>
> Binary Analysis Tool (BAT)
>
> > generic framework for checks of files
> >     written by Armijn
> >     (does not support ubifs)
>
> Checksums
>
> License scanners
>
> FOSSology
>
> > Integrated in openembedded
>
> scancode
>
> > extracts licenses
> >     copyright statements
> >     json output
>
> Ninka

After the audit you can send your lawyers against the company/developer who have used your code (without your permission).